# Cypress: how do you loop waiting for something to become visible (eventually)?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am waiting for a class to be become available in Cypress it might take 2sec, 5min or 20mins to become available, the time is never the same;

But I can't seem to get it to work, it always logs it as {} in the logs, this is despite in chrome dev tools class .very is available.

```
for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
      const $vg = cy.$('.very')
      cy.log($vg)
      if ($vg == ".very") {
        cy.get("#dosomething").click();
      } else {
        cy.log($vg)
        cy.wait(2000);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Read this: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Mixing-Async-and-Sync-code because clearly you are mixing async with sync code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can be used to address the timeout issue.

```
cy.get('.very', { timeout: 10000 })
  .should('be.visible')
  .and('contain', 'Home')
  .click()
```

Recommend checking out this cypress.io documentation:
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values

The top portion of the document gets into the asynchronous nature of cypress which is really important to wrap your head around and it explains why your example code won't work. Here's a key blurb from that document: "*You cannot assign or work with the return values of any Cypress command. Commands are enqueued and run asynchronously.*"

Answer (score -1):

In addition to reviewing the [Cypress documentation for Retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html#Commands-vs-assertions), please refer to the numerous examples in the [Cypress Real World App](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/11/introducing-the-cypress-real-world-app/), [a payment application to demonstrate real-world usage of Cypress testing methods, patterns, and workflows](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-realworld-app), of how to properly structure and write tests.